# How do I change the style of the profile picture holder in a Hugo site?

Tags: markdown, hugo, static-site, blogdown

I'm working with this theme https://themes.gohugo.io/theme/academic/ and would like to modify the profile picture with one of my own. Changing the image is easy but how can I make it appear as a square rather than a circle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This need to be done on the CSS side, Inspect the element and remove the Style Rule border-radius 50%.